# How do I find an INamedTypeSymbol for an instance of ITypeParameterSymbol?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I want to iterate over parameters of a particular INamedTypeSymbol and recurse into them in the case those type parameters are generic themselves. However I can't do that, because the type parameters are returned as ITypeParameterSymbol and the generic parameters are only available on INamedTypeSymbol.

How do I find an INamedTypeSymbol for an instance of ITypeParameterSymbol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `TypeArguments`, not `TypeParameters`.

`TypeParameters` returns the declared type parameters of the member declaration (the open/unconstructed generic type).  These are never named types.

`TypeArguments` returns the types that have been substituted (if the type is a closed/constructed type).